# Compute and Show the range between two dates

Tags: vb.net, date, visual-studio-2008, date-comparison

I need sample code:
Date_today and Expiration date

Situation:
If the license is expired last February 21, 2010, it will compute and show the range within the date_today which is February 21, 2014 until from expiration_date which is February 21, 2010.

Note: Output is the month(s) not the year(s).

Like this: 
Date Today: February 21, 2014
Expiration Date: February 21, 2010
Output: 48 months

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to see how you should ask on-topic questions.

Comment: As I understand, you would like the output in months, not years, months, and days. Correct?

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN - Yes, i need only the month(s).

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE

Only month difference:

```
''' <summary>
''' Shows the month difference between two dates with custom string format.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Date1">Indicates the first date to compare.</param>
''' <param name="Date2">Indicates the second date to compare.</param>
Private Function DateDifference(ByVal Date1 As DateTime,
                                ByVal Date2 As DateTime) As Integer

    Dim MonthDiff As Integer

    Do Until Date1 > Date2
        Date1 = Date1.AddMonths(1)
        MonthDiff += 1
    Loop

    Return MonthDiff - 1

End Function
```

Usage:

```
    Dim MonthDiff As Integer = DateDifference(DateTime.Parse("01/03/2013 00:00:00"),
                                              DateTime.Parse("09/04/2014 01:01:01"))

    MsgBox(String.Format("Month Difference {0}", CStr(MonthDiff)))
```

> ORIGINAL

I'm sure that you could customize this snippet to accomplish your needs.

It returns a custom string format with the differences.

Usage Example:

```
MsgBox(DateDifference(DateTime.Parse("01/03/2013 00:00:00"),
                      DateTime.Parse("09/04/2014 01:01:01"),
                      "{0} Year(s), {1} Month(s), {2} Week(s), {3} Day(s), {4} Hour(s), {5} Minute(s) and {6} Second(s)"
```

Here is:

```
' Date Difference
' ( By Elektro )
'
''' <summary>
''' Shows the difference between two dates with custom string format.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Date1">Indicates the first date to compare.</param>
''' <param name="Date2">Indicates the second date to compare.</param>
''' <param name="StringFormat">
''' Indicates the string format to display the difference, where:
''' {0} = Years, {1} = Months, {2} = Weeks, {3} = Days, {4} = Hours, {5} = Minutes and {6} = Seconds</param>
''' <returns>System.String.</returns>
Private Function DateDifference(ByVal Date1 As DateTime,
                                ByVal Date2 As DateTime,
                                ByVal StringFormat As String) As String

    Dim Time As TimeSpan
    Dim YearDiff As Integer, MonthDiff As Integer, WeekDiff As Integer

    Do Until Date1 > Date2

        Date1 = Date1.AddMonths(1)
        MonthDiff += 1

        If MonthDiff = 12 Then
            YearDiff += 1
            MonthDiff = 0
        End If

    Loop

    MonthDiff -= 1
    Date1 = Date1.AddMonths(-1)
    Time = (Date2 - Date1)
    WeekDiff = (Time.Days \ 7)
    Time = (Time - TimeSpan.FromDays(WeekDiff * 7))

    Return String.Format(StringFormat, YearDiff, MonthDiff, WeekDiff, Time.Days, Time.Hours, Time.Minutes, Time.Seconds)

End Function
```

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct. The person that asked specifically requested that the time is in MONTHS ONLY.

Comment: See my answer. Much more straight forward and clean. None the less, I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

This code returns the difference in months:  (Please note, this is the absolute value. To get the non-absoloute value remove the `Math.Abs()` function.)

```
    Public Shared Function MonthDifference(lValue As DateTime, rValue As DateTime) As Integer
        Return Math.Abs((lValue.Month - rValue.Month) + 12 * (lValue.Year - rValue.Year))
    End Function
```

Usage:

```
    Dim date1 As New Date(2010, 2, 21)
    Dim date2 As Date = Date.Today

    Dim differenceInMonths As Integer = MonthDifference(date2, date1)
```

Here is a more straight forward way, but it does not account for the months that dont have 30 days.

```
    Dim date1 As New Date(2010, 2, 21)
    Dim date2 As Date = Date.Today

    Dim difference As TimeSpan = date2.Subtract(date1)
    Dim differenceInMonths As Integer = difference.TotalDays / 30
```

If you need the answer in a different unit of measure like days, minutes, etc., modify the second method.

Comment: Clean does not mean less lines of code, It's not exact 'cause all months does not have 30 days.

Comment: Added a method that accounts for any type of month.